# Issue in content security policy in chrome extension manifest version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The content security policy value in my chrome extension manifest version 2 is:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"`

Now, i need to migrate to manifest version 3. To do so, I wrote the content security policy value in the following way:

`"content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'", "sandbox": "..."  }`
But when I try to run the extension, the manifest is not loaded and I get the following error

**'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://ssl.google-analytics.com" in directive 'script-src'.**

Can someone please guide me how can I fix the issue ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can't use remote (external) scripts in ManifestV3. See also https://crbug.com/1164452.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @wOxxOm . Can you please tell me what could be the alternative for this ? I can't remove this as i have google analytics in my code.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1164452. Someone managed to use chrome.identity and call Google API directly.